# How to sum rows that are between two "type" values?

Tags: mysql

I have some basic knowledge with PHP+MySQL, but I was wondering if such a function can be done.  If so, how should I go about implementing this?  Any advice will be appreciated!

Below is a table of the data:

```
id |   description         |   amount  |   type   |
---+-----------------------+-----------+----------+
1      FISH BURGER MEAL        NULL        HEADER
2      Burger                  5.40        ITEM
3      Fries (S)               2.20        ITEM
4      Cola (S)                2.00        ITEM
5      SUBTOTAL                ????        SUBTOTAL
```

So the question is:
How can I go about doing a `SUM(amount)` of all `type == "ITEMS" WHERE between a "HEADER" type and a "SUBTOTAL" type?`

The function should return the value of `9.60` in this case.

Thanks!

Comment: What is this kind of database design?

Comment: Normalize your data until it is too late

Comment: thanks guys, i figured it may not work out as planned and yup i need to rethink the database...

sorry i m really bad at this right now, but thanks for getting me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this in pure SQL:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) FROM table WHERE description != "SUBTOTAL"
```

a `NULL` value doesn't add anything to the sum.

But considering that you might have multiple orders in such a table, you should rethink you database design, because those orders will quickly mix in a messy way.

Comment: Thanks the code works as intended but yup I'd imagine it will get messed up real quick.. I will rethink the database since it really seems flawed.